# Use Cursor in fragment class in Android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

The code for retrieving data from database works fine in a class that extends Activity, however the app crashes when I place it in the class in which I need to insert the list elements, this class extends Fragment.

```
package com.autohush.www.dah;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.TimePicker;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivityFragment2 extends Fragment {

    Context ctx = this.getActivity();
    private List<TimeList> TDList = new ArrayList<TimeList>();

    public MainActivityFragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        populateLocationList();
    }

    private void populateLocationList() {
        DBoperations db = new DBoperations(ctx);
        Cursor cr = db.getInformation(db);
        cr.moveToFirst();
        String TimeH, TimeM;
        do {
            TimeH = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(1));
            TimeM = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(2));
            TDList.add((new TimeList(TimeH + ":" + TimeM,"1 hr")));
        }while (cr.moveToNext());
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TimeList> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<TimeList> values) {

            super(context, R.layout.time_list_item,values);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            if( v == null){
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_list_item, parent, false);
            }

            TimeList currLoc = TDList.get(position);

            TextView theTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_list_item_textview1);
            theTextView.setText(currLoc.getTime());

            theTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_list_item_textview2);
            theTextView.setText(currLoc.getDuration());

            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_list_view, container, false);

        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.time_list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<TimeList> adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),TDList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivityFragment2.this.getActivity(),TimePickerPopup.class));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

And This is my crash log... i am new to android. please help.

```
 03-10 18:03:04.142 20856-20856/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.autohush.www.dah, PID: 20856
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                   at com.autohush.www.dah.DBoperations.getInformation(DBoperations.java:47)
                                                   at com.autohush.www.dah.MainActivityFragment2.populateLocationList(MainActivityFragment2.java:42)
                                                   at com.autohush.www.dah.MainActivityFragment2.onCreate(MainActivityFragment2.java:37)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1951)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.ensureFragmentsAreInitialized(BackStackRecord.java:1077)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:1032)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:658)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17442)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                at    android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEve
```

Comment: what is the crash logs

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it crashed.
Context ctx = this.getActivity(); shoud not be at the start, since it otherwise returns a null value.
It should be inside onCreate().